# Partion of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, data, partitions

I have a list like this and want to split it into three sublists. One should contain only the first element the 2nd should contain 8 elements starting from 1.944 to 11 and the third should start from 50 to 1 and should have 7 elements in there. How can I split it? I have a data set of multiple lists of the same kind and wanna split them all the same way.

```
list ={{"Res ", Around[ 2.5, 0.03], Around[ 1.5, 0.66], Around[  0.07, 0.0], Around[ 2.76, 0.357], Around[  6.736, 2.14], Around[ 4.76, 0.8732], Around[ 12.7, 1.08], Around[ 33.7, 3.747], 50, 0.08, 0.01, 1.*10^-8, 4, 1, 1}, {"Res", Around[ 2.0, 0.07], Around[ 1.5, 0.01], Around[  0.21, 0.06], Around[  2.823, 0.68], Around[  6.5965, 2.49], Around[ 3.874, 1.0], Around[ 11.34, 1.1], Around[ 24.3, 3.02], 50, 0.08, 0.01, 1, 4.8, 1, 1}}
```

Comment: If `alist = Alphabet[][[1 ;; 16]]` then `TakeList[alist, {1, 8, 7}]` would get the desired result.

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. and If I have multiple lists of the same kind like an array then I should write the code for all rows. how should I do that ?

Comment: Please load code (not images). Look at `Map`.

Comment: Hi @Miss, your list has the correct format but I think there is a typo as it is not a valid list. There is a mixing of strings and lists. Pasting your `list` in mathematica gives a syntactically broken list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### @Sayed's method using `TakeList`

I can confirm that @Syed's solution works perfectly well:

```
TakeList[#, {1, 8, 7}] & /@ list
```

[image]

##### Note

The reason it might not have worked for you is because you had to tweak a bit the values within `TakeList`.

---

#### Alternative method

Alternatively, a more verbose and less elegant solution:
I think this should answer your question:

```
splitter[list_] := 
  list[[#[[1]] ;; #[[2]]]] & /@ {{1, 1}, {2, 9}, {10, -1}};

splitter[#] & /@ list
```

[image]

---

#### The secondary question

```
list1 = TakeList[#, {1, 8, 7}] & /@ list
list2 = Prepend[#[[2 ;;]], #[[1, 1]]] & /@ list1
```

[image]

Comment: Note that approach given by @Syed in comments is much simpler and gives identical results `splitter[mylist] === TakeList[mylist, {1, 8, 6}]`

Comment: I did see Syed's answer but my mind didn't register it as I had never used (or seen) TakeList until I saw your comment. Indeed `TakeList` is much more elegant of a solution.

Comment: {{"Res", Around[
  1.9`, 0.1`], Around[
  1.2`, 0.03], Around[
  0.01, 0.09], Around[
  3.4, 0.6], Around[
  19.8`, 2.3`], Around[
  0.9, 0.4], Around[
  4.03, 0.38], Around[
  11.2, 3.6], 50, 0.8, 0.01, 5, 
  4.8, 1, 1}{"Res", Around[
  2.08, 0.8], Around[
  1.3`, 0.3`], Around[
  0.6, 0.9], Around[
  2.1, 0.4`], Around[
  21.4`, 1.7`], Around[
  0.5, 0.4`], Around[
  6.2, 0.4], Around[
  13.9`, 2.6`], 50, 0.8, 0.01, 
  6, 4.8, 1, 1}}

Comment: How can I apply this code to the entire array with multiple lists?

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Let me know if that works for you. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I worked perfectly :).

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If you could, please mark the answer as "accepted" but also please give @Sayed's comment a upvote as he contributed to the final answer.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid curly braces around the first element only and the rest of the partition remains the same?

Comment: You could, but it is typically easier to simply add [[1]] on that particular element when you construct your desired list.

Comment: Actually, I am a beginner in Mathematica. I do not know what the code should look like.

Comment: Not a problem. have a look here:https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html. essentially, if you type `list[[1,1]]` you take the first element of the first element.

Comment: I tried TakeList[list, {[[1]], 8, 9}] & /@ list and TakeList[#, {[[1]], 8, 9}] & /@ list both but it dosent work.

Comment: Before you use a function you should read the documentation to get an idea of how it works. You can see the documentation by clicking on the function and pressing F1. Also please do go through the link I sent earlier. It is by far one of the most useful links there are for mathematica.

Comment: I've amended my answer. I hope that helps.