# Partition of lists with specified elements

Tags: list-manipulation, data, dataset, partitions, numeric-array

I have an array like this and want to split it into sublists. It should contain the first element "Res" without curly braces and the one sublist starts from 2 to the 9th column the 3rd should start from 10th column to 16th.

[image: Array]

[image: ResultantArray]

Comment: I tried      TakeList[#, {1, 8, 9}] & /@ list            but it makes the first element also a sublist which I do not want,

Comment: As was mentioned on your earlier post, provide your data in copy and paste-able form so that we don't have to retype it.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's walk through this in a bit of detail. First we need some data, and since you haven't provided any in copy-paste-able form, I'll make some up:

```
list = {Take[Alphabet[], 16], Take[Alphabet[], -16]}
```

`{{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"},  {"k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}}`

You said you tried `TakeList[#, {1, 8, 9}] & /@ list`, but since you only have 16 elements in each list (unless I miscounted), that will generate error messages. There are two remedies. First, match the length of your input list exactly:

```
TakeList[#, {1, 8, 7}] & /@ list
```

Alternatively, use `All` to finish off (this would be nice if you don't always know the exact length):

```
newList = TakeList[#, {1, 8, All}] & /@ list
```

(I assigned this to the variable `newList` so we can use it later.)

Both of these produce something that looks like this:

```
{{{"a"}, {"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"}, {"j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"}}, 
{{"k"}, {"l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s"}, {"t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}}}
```

Okay, now you don't want those first elements to be a list--that's a job for `FlattenAt`. We want to flatten at the first position, and we want to do it for all lists in our `newList` structure. So, we'll use `Map` again:

```
FlattenAt[1] /@ newList
```

`{{"a", {"b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"}, {"j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p"}}, {"k", {"l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s"}, {"t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}}}`

Comment: Thanks! it works but at the same time gives me an error. Too few arguments given at FlattenAt.

Comment: What's the exact error message (including the tag)? What version of Mathematica are you using (FlattenAt has been around a long time, but might as well cover our bases). And did you run the exact code I provided above? In that sequence? You didn't skip ahead to trying to change it for your own data before verifying that the code worked as provided?

Comment: I wonder how long the operator form of `FlattenAt` has been available?  Nothing [documented](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FlattenAt.html#:~:text=FlattenAt%20%5B%20list%2C%20n%5D%20flattens%20out%20a%20sublist,negative%2C%20the%20position%20is%20counted%20from%20the%20end.) about this it would seem, but maybe `FlattenAt[#,1]&/@newList` would work?

Comment: @user1066 good suggestion. OP also said "it works", so I'm confused. Will wait for more info before updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you require something like the following?

```
Through[{First, Splice@TakeList[Rest@#,{8,7}]&}[#]]&/@list2

(* 
   {
    {a, {b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, {j, k, l, m, n, o, p}},  
    {k, {l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s}, {t, u, v, w, x, y, z}}
   }
*)
```

Or, taking the example data from your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/283032/106):

```
Through[{First, Splice@TakeList[Rest@#,{8,7}]&}[#]]&/@list


(* 
    {
      {Res , {Around[2.5, 0.03], Around[1.5, 0.66], 0.07, 
              Around[2.76, 0.357], Around[6.736, 2.14], 
              Around[4.76, 0.8732], Around[12.7, 1.08],Around[33.7, 3.747]},                        
              {50, 0.08, 0.01, 1. 10^-8  , 4, 1, 1}
      }, 

      {Res, {Around[2., 0.07], Around[1.5, 0.01], Around[0.21, 0.06], 
             Around[2.823, 0.68], Around[6.5965, 2.49], Around[3.874, 1.], 
             Around[11.34, 1.1], Around[24.3, 3.02]}, 
            {50, 0.08, 0.01, 1, 4.8, 1, 1}}
      }

*)
```

where `list2` is taken from [lericr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/84894/lericr)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283044/106), and `list` is taken from your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/283032/106)

```
list2 = {Take[Alphabet[], 16], Take[Alphabet[], -16]}
```

Comment: Hello everyone. Thank you for the help. It worked out for me.

Comment: And, of course, `FoldPairList/TakeDrop` may be substituted for `TakeList`. For example: `Through[{First@#&, Splice@FoldPairList[TakeDrop,Rest@#,{8,7}]&}[#]]&/@list2`